# Most appropriate graph layout for VRP in R?

Tags: r, graph-theory, vehicle-routing

I have been working in a Shiny/R app that solves the VRP. I have already got the solution but I now want to plot it using graphs (more specifically Igraph).

I would like to minimize crossings and, if possible, get something close to this:
[image: VRP]
I was wondering if there was a special/better layout to use.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.